# type 'List<Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>' in type cast - Flutter

Tags: java, flutter, dart, flutter-method-channel

I am trying to call a MethodChannel which is supposed to return a List<Map<String, String>>. I tried using both, invokeMethod as well as invokeListMethod, but I get some sort of type casting error.

For example, in case of .invokeMethod as

```
      final List<Map<String, dynamic>>? tableData =
          await platform.invokeMethod<List<Map<String, String>>>(getTableData, <String, String>{
        'table': selectedTable!,
      });
```

i get the following error message

```
type 'List<Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>' in type cast
```

while using invokeListMethod as

```
      final List<Map<String, dynamic>>? tableData =
          await platform.invokeListMethod<Map<String, dynamic>>(getTableData, <String, String>{
        'table': selectedTable!,
      });
```

I get the following error

```
I/flutter ( 2718): type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast
```

On the native side, i am trying to send ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> and according to the list of datatypes mentioned in the methodchannel docs, i think, it should work. So not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Ah BTW.... i know it will not give an error if I remove the typing, but then it wont play well with type suggestions and stuff.

Comment: try using JSON and confirm you are getting the correct data as response.

Comment: I did that... but i am getting error like... Unsupported values as ```PlatformException(GENERIC_EXCEPTION_FAILED_GET_TABLE_DATA, Failed to get the tables data, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported value: {"columns":["SalutationID","Salutation","Order"],"columnsCount":3,"rows":[1,"Mr.",null,2,"Mrs.",null,3,"Ms.",null,4,"Dr.",null],"totalRows":4}, null)```

Comment: convert the json to string and pass